# How to highlight background of duplicate values in returned resultset (Flask-Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, duplicates, resultset

Im working on a Python-Flask project and have a small question:

I want to highlight the background of the  when the returned resultset contains duplicated values.
**Note:** the values are Integers.

A small code snippet attached:

**Code:**

```
<tbody>
{% for result in results %}
<tr> 
<td> {{ result.Batch_Naam }} </td>

**
<td {% if result.ISSI == result.ISSI %}
class="check_duplicated"> {{ result.ISSI }}
{% else %} {{ result.ISSI }}
{% endif %}</td>**

<td> {{ result.TEI }} </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

**CSS:**

```
.check_duplicated{
background-color: darkorange;
color: black;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

I tried another for loop but thats not working on Integers. Do i need to convert them to string first or is there a built-in function for looping through Integers? Or do i need to do something else?

I changed the for loop to an if statement which i did tot test the rest of the code (see above).

I hope you guys can push me a little bit in the right direction. Thanks!

Grtz

See the text above. I tried several things. I need an push in the right direction.